# how to detect if FTP is working or not onremote machine?

Tags: ftp, network-programming, tcl, staf

I have 3 machines(A, B & C) connected to a Router. A,B & C are in same subnet. All these three machines are interconnected using STAF. I am using machine A as an FTP server & machine B as an FTP client. Using STAF command from machine C I am starting FTP program (TCL script) on machine B.

Now the question is, How C will know whether FTP traffic is flowing between A & B?

Answer (score 0):

The [ftp package](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/ftp/ftp.html) allows you to specify a progress monitor callback in the `ftp::Open` command:

```
package require ftp

proc progressMessage {bytesSoFar} {
    puts "Transferred $bytesSoFar; looking good..."
}
set handle [ftp::Open $A $user $pass -progress progressMessage]

# Everything after this is just standard for the ftp package
if {$handle < 0} {
    error "could not connect"
}
if {![ftp::Get $handle $remoteFile $localFile]} {
    ftp::Close $handle
    error "could not transfer"
}
ftp::Close $handle
puts "Transfer completed"
```

This will print a message every time a chunk is transferred (the chunk size is configurable in the options to `ftp::Open` via the `-blocksize` option; it's 4096 by default). On modern networks, this is probably going to write messages very rapidly…

Answer (score -1):

```
package require ftp
set handle [::ftp::Open $host $user $passwd]
if {$handle < 0} {
    error "Connection refused!"
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Mere code is not an answer, and this code doesn't detect whether 'FTP traffic is flowing between A and B'. -1